# Is there a way to force UFW firewall accept only connections from local network? Better practices?

Tags: networking, security, firewall, ufw, kde-connect

I was trying to setup the UFW firewall to allow my smartphone connecting my Ubuntu with KDE-connect and I saw this recommended configuration for UFW in KDE community (https://community.kde.org/KDEConnect):

```
sudo ufw allow 1714:1764/udp
sudo ufw allow 1714:1764/tcp
```

But this raise me some question around this...
Can this configuration be considered a vulnerability? Can someone **outside my local network** use these ports to get access to my data?

So I thouhgt to use this configuration instead:

```
sudo ufw allow proto tcp from 192.168.0.0/24 to any port 1714:1764
sudo ufw allow proto udp from 192.168.0.0/24 to any port 1714:1764
```

Is this a better practice to avoid a vulnerability and **force UFW to accept only connections within my local network**?

Comment: Somebody out in the wide world could use those ports IF 1) You had them forwarded through your router AND 2) An application (KDE Connect) is bound to those ports AND 3) That application has exploitable vulnerabilities. You are in complete control of #1 and #2, and you have a input/influence over #3.

Comment: Thanks @user535733! Anyway, is there any advantage if I use my approach (specifying the local IP) instead the recommended one?

Answer (score 2):

Hardly, but it depends how your environment is set up. user535733 already gave a nice example.
Better practice - it can be if you like or need strict approach.
You can also look at your Ethernet interface:

```
ip -c a
```

Let’s say it is eth0.
So then you can do something like this:

```
sudo ufw allow in on eth0 proto tcp from 192.168.1.0/29 to any port 1714:1764
```

You can also check a range of given IP addresses to see if they do fit your needs:

```
ipcalc 192.168.1.0/29
```

Comment: Thanks @sudoawesome! In terms of security, what's the purpose of specifying the Ethernet interface? To avoid someone connect from outside my local network?

Comment: For this example yes. But in general it means that you have option to limit access to your device, on specific interface. For instance, you can combine that and do the same for local IP addresses as you wanted.